# Multiple data models with MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, magicalrecord

I inherited a project using MagicalRecord that was using a single Core Data data model called Foo.xcdatamodel.  In the code I saw they were using

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"Foo"];
```

I need to create another data model which I will call Bar.xcdatamodel and I am wondering if I need to make another call to

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"Bar"];
```

Also do I need to pass the data model names in the method as they did or was that just something they did for consistency?

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of MagicalRecord will load all managed object models from your main application bundle and merge them into a single model. So, you can have multiple model files, and MagicalRecord will load all of them, and treat them as one file. This behavior is based on the code for the [NSManagedObjectModel MagicalRecord additions](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/v2.3.0/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObjectModel%2BMagicalRecord.m#L15).

Comment: OK thanks, so I only need one call to setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed?